# How do I parse this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> 君がかわいいってことには変わらないから安心して

I understand all the words I think but don't understand the grammar. What does こと do here? Does it mean "The part of you that is cute"? Does 安心して mean be calm or be at peace here? I can only understand it now as

> Because the cute things about you dont change, be at peace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I would go about it.
君がかわいい

> You are cute

ってこと

> The thing/fact

変わらない

> Does not change

安心して

> Don't worry.

君がかわいいってことには変わらないから安心して

> The fact that you are cute is not gonna change so don't worry.

Comment: Ah! The reason I couldn't understand is because I was parsing に　as emphasized に but its more a emphasized が！

Comment: You did not even notice the unnaturalness of the sentence.

Answer (score 5):

The sentence sounds strange for me and I would prefer either of the following, with a slight difference in nuance:

```
君がかわいいってことには変わりがないから安心して

There is no change to the fact that you are cute, so don't worry.
```

or

```
君がかわいいってことは変わらないから安心して

The fact that you are cute does not change so don't worry.
```

Comment: Err, it comes from a native speaker and I showed them this post and they said the grammar is fine.

Comment: Interesting, googling does indeed suggest that it is correct. I think that it sounds strange though, because the intransitive verb 変る needs a subject that is undergoing the change, which in this case should be "the fact that she is cute", but adding the に particle makes it not a subject any more. Sorry for my confusion... I hope someone can clear this out for me

Comment: には is emphasizdx が. I was confused for the exact same reason, even arguing with the native haha. Finally they realized the confusion and explained it properly.

Comment: @Tyler H I'm a native speaker but I still find the sentence grammatically off even though it can slip from time to time. If it was 変わりない, it'd be fine though.

Comment: Someone else said that as well actually. Ill ask the original speaker bjt they typed it to me so maybe its a typo.

Comment: I also think this sounds much more natural as 変わり(が)ない

Answer (score 1):

Both of these are correct.
君がかわいいってことには変わりがないから安心して
or
君がかわいいってことは変わらないから安心して

When you use [ことには], it means [into that fact]..(には stands for into)
and when you use [ことは], it means, [the fact].
Now we can easily make out the sense.
... ことには変わりがない ...==>No change into the fact.
... ことは変わらない ... ==> Fact doesn't change.

Hope it helps.